# IntelliSense: identifier "userexist" is undefined in my Visual Studio c++ project

Tags: c++, intellisense

I have a header file BookStore.header where I created a class Users, with  private atributes:

```
int id_user;
char* u_name;
char* email;
char password[20];
static unsigned int nr_user;
```

getters,setters,constructors,destructor and

```
    User(const User&);
    User &operator=(const User&);
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, User&);
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, User);
    bool isLogIn();
    bool userexist(ifstream& , User& );
    int get_users_count(ifstream &);
```

Then i created a BookStore.cpp where I included `#include"BookStore.h"` and implemened all methods,constructors+

```
bool User::isLogIn(){
    string username, password, file_line;
    cout << "enter username:";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "enter pass:";
    cin >> password;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("users.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()){
        cout << "Error while opening the file...";
    }
    else{
        string str;
        while (getline(infile, str)){

            vector<string> newVector = split(str);
            /*for (string line; getline(infile, line);)
            {*/
            string username_from_file = newVector[1];
            string password_from_file = newVector[3];
            if ((username_from_file.compare(username) == 0) && (password_from_file.compare(password)) == 0){
                return true;
            }
            /*}*/

        }
    }
    return false;
    /*  if (un == username&& pw == password){
    return true;
    }
    else
    return false;

    }*/
}
bool  userexist(ifstream& file, User& u){

    string str;
    while (getline(file, str)){

        vector<string> newVector = split(str);
        cout << newVector.size();
        if (newVector.size() > 0){
            string username_from_file = newVector[1];

            if ((username_from_file.compare(u.getName()) == 0)){
                file.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return false;
}

int get_users_count(ifstream &file){
    string str;
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(file, str)){
        vector<string> newVector = split(str);
        if (newVector.size() > 0){
            string iduser = newVector[0];
            i++;
        }

    }
    file.close();
    return i;
}
```

My problem is in main class in which I include "BookStore.h"

```
                {
                    cin >> u5;
                    ifstream infile;
                    infile.open("users.txt");
                    if (!userexist(infile, u5)){
                        infile.open("users.txt");
                        int numbers_ids =  get_users_count(infile);
                        u5.set_id(&numbers_ids);
                        outFile << u5.get_id() << " " << u5.getName() << " " << u5.getEmail() << " " << u5.getPass() << " " << endl;
                        //outFile << u5;
                        cout << "Registration succesfull!";
                        cout << endl;
                        outFile.close();
                    }
```

When i run this I get 
    **1 IntelliSense: identifier "userexist" is undefined

    2 IntelliSense: identifier "get_users_count" is undefined**

Comment: Does the compilation fail ? IntelliSense might just be not up to date (eg: code not analyzed, etc).

Comment: Is your file really named `BookStore.header`? (It should be `BookStore.h`, the same name you use with `#include`)